# I'm continually getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in my program, and I don't know how to pinpoint it. How do I solve this?

Tags: java

I'm working on a recursion project for myself, and even though this program was working previously, it stopped working and gives an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error on line 161. I'm pretty confused at the moment, and it would be incredibly helpful if any of you guys could help.

Here's the code so far, although it's kinda long --

Thanks in advance!

````
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Object;
 
public class KevinBacon {
 
    public static void options() {
        System.out.println("Select Options (Enter Q to Quit)");
                System.out.println("1. Bacon Degrees of Freedom");
                System.out.println("2. Add Entry");
                System.out.println("3. Delete Entry");
    }
    public static String tabs(int degrees) {
                String tab = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < degrees; i++) {
                        tab = tab.concat("\t");
                }
                return tab;
        }
 
    //Recursion
    public static int DOF(String mainActorNames, String names, String masterList[][], int degrees) {
        degrees++;
        String temp[][] = masterList;
 
        ArrayList<String> movieList = getMovieList(names, temp);
 
 
        if (movieList.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < movieList.size(); i++) {
                if (temp.length > 0) {
                    ArrayList<String> actorList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
                        if (temp[j][1].contains(movieList.get(i))) {
                            actorList.add(temp[j][0]);
                        }
                    }
                    for (int kb = 0; kb < actorList.size(); kb++) {
                        if (actorList.get(kb).contains("Kevin Bacon")) {
                        System.out.println("Recursion level: " + degrees + "\n" + tabs(degrees) + names
                                                                        + " acted with " + actorList.get(kb) + "in movie " + movieList.get(i));
                                                        System.out.println(tabs(degrees) + mainActorNames + " has Bacon Number " + degrees + "\n");
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            if (!actorList.get(kb).contains(names)) {
                                System.out.println("Recursion level: " + degrees + "\n" + tabs(degrees) + names
                                                                        + " acted with " + actorList.get(kb) + "in movie " + movieList.get(i));
                                DOF(mainActorNames, actorList.get(kb), delTempArr(movieList.get(i), temp), degrees);
                            }
                            else if (!actorList.get(kb).contains(names)) {
                            //placeholder
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(tabs(degrees - 1) + "No Movie Available in Database for " + names);
        }
        return 0;
    }
 
    //adds movies to temp array
    private static ArrayList<String> getMovieList(String actor, String temp[][]) {
        ArrayList<String> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            if (temp[i][0].contains(actor)) {
                movieList.add(temp[i][1]);
            }
        return movieList;
    }
 
 
    //Remove scanned movies and stuff from the temp array
    public static String[][] delTempArr(String movieNames, String temp[][]) {
        String temp2[][] = new String[temp.length-2][3];
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
            if (!temp[j][1].contains(movieNames)) {
                temp2[count][0] = temp[j][0];
                temp2[count][1] = temp[j][1];
                temp2[count][2] = temp[j][2];
                count++;
            }
        }
    return temp2;
    }
 
    //Welcome to the main method
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //welcome to my variables, please look at my wares
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("list.txt"));
        Scanner file1 = new Scanner(new File("list.txt"));
        int degrees = 1;
        ArrayList<String> kevMovies = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> allMovies = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<>();
        int counter = 0;
        String line;
        String movieName;
        String actorName;
        String year;
        boolean bool;
        boolean bool1;
 
        //determines size of the arr
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("list.txt"));
        counter = 0;
        while (read.readLine() != null) {
            counter++;
        }
        read.close();
 
        //welcome to the big boy array
        String theBigOne[][] = new String[counter][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            line = file.nextLine();
            String[] sploit = line.split(" ");
            actorName = sploit[0] + sploit[1];
            movieName = "";
            year = sploit[sploit.length - 1];
 
            for (int j = 2; j < sploit.length - 1; j++) {
                movieName = movieName + sploit[j] + " ";
            }
            theBigOne[i][0] = actorName;
            theBigOne[i][1] = movieName;
            theBigOne[i][2] = year;
            names.add(actorName);
            allMovies.add(movieName);
            years.add(year);
        }
        String poob = "";
        //While loop :(((
        while (!poob.contentEquals("Q")) {
            FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter("list.txt", true);
            Formatter output = new Formatter(filewriter);
            options();
            poob = input.nextLine();
            if (poob.contentEquals("1") || poob.contentEquals("2") || poob.contentEquals("3")) {
                int option = Integer.parseInt(poob);
            //Bacon Number
                if (option == 1) {
                    bool=true;
                    degrees = 0;
                    System.out.println("Enter Actor Name:");
                    String nameOfActor = input.nextLine();
                    String mainActorNames = nameOfActor;
                    //Check the bounds!
                    String[] split3 = nameOfActor.split(" ");
                    //Number restriction
                        for (char c : nameOfActor.toCharArray()) {
                            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                            bool = false;
                            }
                        }
                    if (split3.length == 2 && bool) {
                        ArrayList<String> summary = new ArrayList<String>();
                        DOF(mainActorNames, nameOfActor, theBigOne, degrees);
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                        bool = true;
                    }
                }
                //the second option
                else if (option == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Actor Name:");
                    String inputName = input.nextLine();
                //Bounds
                    String[] split1 = inputName.split(" ");
                    bool = true;
                    for (char c : inputName.toCharArray()) {
                        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                            bool = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (split1.length == 2 && bool) {
                        System.out.println("Enter movie name:");
                        String movieInput = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Enter year:");
                        String yearInput = input.next();
                    //Bounds
                        String[] split2 = yearInput.split(" ");
                        bool1 = true;
                        for (char c : yearInput.toCharArray()) {
                            if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                                bool1 = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (bool1 && split2.length == 1) {
                            output.format("\n%s %s %s", inputName, movieInput, yearInput);
                            output.close();
                            bool = true;
                            bool1 = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                            bool = true;
                            bool1 = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //the third and final option
                else if (option == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Actor Name:");
                                    String inputtedName = input.nextLine();
                            //Bounds
                                    String[] split6 = inputtedName.split(" ");
                                    bool = true;
                                        for (char c : inputtedName.toCharArray()) {
                                                 if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                             bool = false;
                                             }
                                    }
                                        if (split6.length == 2 && bool) {
                                                 System.out.println("Enter movie name:");
                                                 String movieInput = input.nextLine();
                                                 System.out.println("Enter year:");
                                                 String yearInput = input.next();
                                      //Bounds
                                             String[] split2 = yearInput.split(" ");
                                             bool1 = true;
                                                 for (char c : yearInput.toCharArray()) {
                                                         if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                                                                   bool1 = false;
                             }
                        }
                        if (bool1 && split2.length == 1) {
                            String del = inputtedName + " " + movieInput + " " + yearInput;
                            String currDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                            Path path = Paths.get(currDir + "/list.txt");
                            Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
                            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
                            content = content.replaceAll(del, "");
                            Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                            bool = true;
                            bool1 = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                        bool = true;
                        bool1 = true;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                    bool = true;
                    bool1 = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Use your IDE's debugger, set an exception breakpoint on ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, let it run until it hits the breakpoint, and then inspect the variable values on all (recursive) stack frames that led to the exception. Knowing how to use debugging tools is as important as knowing how to write some program.